# Find and search for a double in an array and return its indices? Is this an array element swap method?)

Tags: java

This is my first question. These 2 create method questions, were on a quiz I took. Create a method, to find a radius, double r. Return the array and its indices, from the 2d circles array. If you can't find double r, return {-1,-1}.**

```
public int[] void findCircleWithRadius(Circle[][] circles, double r) {

    for(int i = 0; i<circles.length-1; i++) { //search the row
        for(int j = 0; j<circles[0].length; j++) { //search each column
            Circle temp = circles[i][j];
            if(temp == r) r = temp; 
            else return "{-1,-1}";
        }
     }

     return circles.indexOf(r);
}
```

Create a method to swap the circles, using the findCircleWithRadius method.

```
public static void swapCircles(Circles[][] circles, double r1, double r2) {

    Circle radius1 = r1.findCircleWithRadius();
    Circle radius2 = r2.findCircleWithRadius();
    Circle temp2 = radius2;

    radius2 = radius1;
    radius1 = temp2;
}
```

Comment: To earn the rep ask good questions and provide useful answers. Start from reading following help sections: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What does the compiler say to this code, especially to this if statement? How can the Circle object and the double be compared? And even if this was possible: Please read your own code carefully, because that if is checking for equality, and says "if they are equal assign the other to the first". What sense does this make?

Comment: By the way: Does anyone mention a two-dimensional array in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to fix in your first example:

1. Right now, `j < circles[0].length` means that only one column is being searched: column `0`. You'll want `j < circles[i].length` to search every column by row.
2. `if (temp == r)` means you're comparing a `Circle` and a `double`. I'm not familiar with the circle class, but I believe you'll want to replace instead of `Circle temp = circles[i][j]` with `double temp = circles[i][j].getRadius();`.
3. You want to return as soon as you find the matching `Circle`, so you have some things a little backwards. With my new revisions, `if (temp == r)` will now activate the code if you have found the correct radius. That means below that `if` statement, you'll want `return {i, j};`. That will return the current circle's (which has the correct radius) indicies.
4. The last statement will be called if none of the radius tests return true, so where you have `return circles.indexOf(r);`, you'll want `return {-1, -1};`.
5. Since arrays are 0-based, and less than already means one minus the value, you do not need `- 1` in `i < circles.length - 1`

On your second example:

Your `findCircleWithRadius` method has two paramaters: a `Circle[][]` and a `double`. That means you'll need to give it those. The method you created is not called from a double, as well, so you can't say `r1.findCircleWithRadius();` 
Additionally, you need to use the `int[]` that the `findCircleWithRadius` passes you to get those `Circle`'s.
Therefore, your first lines in `swapCircles` should be:

```
int[] rad1 = this.findCircleWithRadius(circles, r1); // Get the coordinates of the first circle by passing the 2D array, and the radius you're looking for.
int[] rad2 = this.findCircleWithRadius(circles, r2); // Get the coordinates of the second circle by passing the 2D array, and the radius you're looking for.

Circle radius1 = circles[rad1[0]][rad1[1]]; // Circle 1 is equal to the Circle in the array that has coordinates of the first index in the coordinates, and the second index of the coordinates. (circles[x, y])
Circle radius2 = circles[rad2[0]][rad2[1]]; // Circle 2 is equal to the Circle in the array that has coordinates of the first index in the coordinates, and the second index of the coordinates. (circles[x, y])
```

In conclusion, the completed code with my revisions will be as follows:

```
public int[] void findCircleWithRadius(Circle[][] circles, double r) {

for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) { //search the row
    for(int j = 0; j < circles[i].length; j++) { //search each column
        double temp = circles[i][j].getRadius();
        if(temp == r)
        return {i, j};
    }
 }
 return {-1, -1};
 }

public static void swapCircles(Circles[][] circles, double r1, double r2) {

int[] rad1 = this.findCircleWithRadius(circles, r1);
int[] rad2 = this.findCircleWithRadius(circles, r2);
Circle radius1 = circles[rad1[0]][rad1[1]];
Circle radius2 = circles[rad2[0]][rad2[1]];

Circle temp2 = radius2;

radius2 = radius1;
radius1 = temp2;
}
```

Otherwise, everything else is looking pretty good! I hope you did well on your quiz! Please let me know if you have any further questions about anything I have said so I can make sure you understand this fully.

Comment: Please review, I have added a few more issues and compiled it all at the bottom. I know you're still learning, but in the future you'll want to follow through exactly what your program is going to do by making a pretend 2D array and running the methods with sample radius', or similar practices.

Comment: Also, if I have satisfied your question, please mark my answer as accepted so we do not receive duplicate answers.